# check if there is a <select> within the parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I do something like this: check if I have a `<select>` within the parent div, if there is one, I display something.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way would be to filter with the [`:has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector

```
if ( $(this).parent(':has(select)').length ){
  // display something..
}
```

If on the other hand the `select` is not deeper than the current element, you might want to use the [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method

```
if ( $(this).siblings('select').length ){
  // display something..
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If there is one, the length of the jQuery object containing matched elements is `> 0`. Because `if` clauses get executed when the condition is 'truthy' (everything except values like `0`, `undefined` etc) you are safe to eliminate the `> 0`:

```
if($(this).parent().find("select").length) {
    // there is one, display something
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/length/

http://api.jquery.com/parent/

http://api.jquery.com/find/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, check the length property of the result set array.

```
if ($('#parentDiv select').length > 0) {
    alert('There is at least one <select> inside the div!');
}
```

**[jsFiddle Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/RikudoSennin/cA4SP/)**.

Comment: Corrected answer and example.

Answer (score 1):

with jquery you can select nested elements.

try something like this.

```
if( 0 < $('select', $('#div_id') ).length ) {
    alert( 'Select box in the div' );
} else {
    alert( 'NO Select box in the div' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use function *closest*

```
<html>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($("#txt").closest("div").find("select").length){
        alert("Found it");      
    }
});
</script>
<div>
    <select id="heart"><option value="Hello"></option></select>
    <input type="text" id="txt" />
</div>
</html>
```